# Parsing xml file with regex: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, regex, xml, xml-parsing

i am trying to get some data from xml file with regex (i know that i should propably use some xml parser, but regex seems more simple if you havent used any xml parsers before)

Here's my python code:

```
import datetime,re
date= datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d')

output = open(r'C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\Kodi\addons\plugin.video.videoaddon\resources\epg.xml', 'r')
match = re.compile('start="%s(.+?)\s.+?".+?channel="Bravo (US)"\s><title>(.+?)</title>'%(date)).findall(output)
for start,title in match:
    print(start,title)
```

I get `TypeError: Expected string or buffer`

Can anyone explain why I get this error?

Additional info what I am trying to do, if someone is interested:

XML file example: http://pastebin.com/9yC1FTYu
I know that this xml isn't well formatted, but that's how I get it from the software API.

Basically I need to get: 
Last part of `start` timestamp, first part must match date, and the `<title>` text. And I need to get these where `channel` matches `Bravo (US)`.

Comment: The XML is not malformed, so why not use a proper XML parser?

Comment: As i sayed, i never had experience with xml parsers, and i just dont know how to do it. Regex seemed more simple way of doing it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the *file object* to the `pattern.findall()` method. You'd have to *read* the file first:

```
pattern = re.compile('start="%s(.+?)\s.+?".+?channel="Bravo (US)"\s><title>(.+?)</title>'%(date))
filename = r'C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\Kodi\addons\plugin.video.videoaddon\resources\epg.xml'
with open(filename, 'r') as xmlfile:
    match = pattern.findall(output.read())
```

However, you should really use a XML parser here. The standard library comes with the [ElementTree API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

filename = r'C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\Kodi\addons\plugin.video.videoaddon\resources\epg.xml'
tree = ET.parse(filename)
for programme in tree.findall(".//programme[@channel='Bravo (US)']"):
    showtime = programme.attrib['start']
    if showtime.startswith(date):
        print showtime[8:14], programme.find('title').text
```

If you installed [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) you can use more complex XPath queries, including one that searches for the date:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

filename = r'C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\Kodi\addons\plugin.video.videoaddon\resources\epg.xml'
date_predicate = '[starts-with(@start, "{}")]'.format(date)
tree = ET.parse(filename)
for programme in tree.xpath('.//programme[@channel="Bravo (US)"]' + date_predicate):
    showtime = programme.attrib['start']
    print showtime[8:14], programme.find('title').text
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this ElementTree seems perfect for job.  I cannot use lxml, because i will run python script on kodi/xmbc and i can only use libaries from original python.  I just have one more question: how could i take other part of timestamp from start tag into string ?  For example: start="20150925**230000** +0300" ?  So i could eventually print out show starttime and show name:  print(starttime,title)  I really appreaciate your help, thank you again!

Comment: @user2033139: you'd have to parse that out using string manipulation; `from datetime import time` and `showtime = el.attrib['start']` and `timestamp = time(int(showtime[8:10]), int(showtime[10:12]), int(showtime[12:14]))` would give you a `datetime.time()` object with just the time section (ignoring the timezone).

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the file using `read()` or otherwise, file object only stored in the output variable not the contents.

```
output = open(r'C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Roaming\Kodi\addons\plugin.video.videoaddon\resources\epg.xml', 'r').read()
                                                                                                              ^
```